# How to convert string dd.mm.yyyy to date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column field of `varchar` type in format `dd.mm.yyyy`. I am trying to convert this `varchar` field to date time in SQL server using

```
CONVERT(Datetime, LTRIM(RTRIM([Completion Date])), 102)
```

but it gives me error 'Conversion of `varchar` type to date type results in out of range value'

How to convert this field to `datetime` format?

Comment: Do you have something like a February 30th or September 31st day? How about using `TRY_CONVERT` and then check to see where the `NULL` values are to find out where your error is?

Comment: Please show us some data for the `[Completion Date]` column.

Answer (score 3):

use style `104` (`dd.mm.yyyy`) instead of `102` (`yyyy.mm.dd`)

```
CONVERT(Datetime, LTRIM(RTRIM([Completion Date])), 104)
```

Also the field of type `varchar` so there could be some bad dates which needs to be eliminated before the conversion .

If you are using `SQL SERVER 2012+` then use `TRY_CONVERT`, for bad dates it will result `NULL`

```
TRY_CONVERT(Datetime, LTRIM(RTRIM([Completion Date])), 104)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always use this:

```
 SELECT convert(datetime, '23/07/2009', 102)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
 SELECT convert(date, '21.12.2016', 104)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert with date and datetime as below:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '27-09-2013', 104)
SELECT convert(date, '27-09-2013', 104)
```